# how to force ssl with default-ssl without DNS?

Tags: 12.10, apache2, dns, url, https

I know this has been covered everywhere, and I've actually made this work on another server, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I have this

```
RewriteEngine   on
RewriteCond     %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

currently in `/etc/apache2/conf.d/site.conf`.  No go.

I also tried it in `/var/www/.htaccess`.  No go.  I couldn't even get an improperly formatted `/var/www/.htaccess` to cause 500 error.  (Does a setting have to be changed to use `.htaccess`?)

I am not using a domain name, and I'm using `a2ensite default-ssl`.

**SPDY & FastCGI**

I don't know if this matters, but I installed SPDY per these instructions http://www.howtoforge.com/using-mod_spdy-with-apache2-on-ubuntu-12.10 and FastCGI by `apt-get install libapache2-mod-fastcgi`, `a2enmod actions fastcgi alias`, and `services apache2 restart`.

Comment: What about a much simpler `Redirect` directive in the non-SSL `VirtualHost` block? mod_rewrite seems overkill for this, I think.

Comment: @Celada Thank-you for looking!  I only care if it works.  Could you post full detail in answer?  I'm a programmer and want to keep server-admin to a minimum hence the choice of the amazing ubuntu (i love how I can get a server up and running in five minutes!) since I'm only about a month old in linux.

Comment: Is there any error logged on /var/log/apache2/error.log? Is the module rewrite enabled? `sudo a2enmod rewrite` to enable.

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy on further examination, I guess plain `Redirect` won't work for you because you have a dynamic server name. For `Redirect` you have to know the hostname of the redirect target in advance. Hopefully someone will find the bug for you. I personally find Apache rewrite rules confusing :-(

Comment: @EricCarvalho I did turn on `rewrite`. Let me get back to you on the error log. Thanks!

Comment: @Celada I appreciate your knowledge on this!  Yeah, it was a server that had DNS that I could make work with this script.

Comment: @EricCarvalho I think I found the problem thanks to your suggestion, but I'm not sure how to fix it.  `[warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `localhost.localdomain' does NOT match server name!?`

Comment: It's just a warning. Can you access `https://<ip-address>`? If it works that's OK. I found [this](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS) documentation that recommends `RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]`. Can you test it?

Comment: @EricCarvalho yep, my https works.  that rule didn't work either :/  Thank you for your suggestion!  I also added information in my question